# Equals(...) does not return the same after boxing

Tags: .net, vb.net, comparison, equals, value-type

See the following code:

```
Private Function EqualsNothing(ByVal item As Object) As Boolean
  Return item.Equals(Nothing)
End Function

Console.WriteLine(0.Equals(Nothing)) ' True
Console.WriteLine(EqualsNothing(0)) ' False
```

How do I avoid `Equals` from returning something different after boxing structures? Is there some way to call the original `Equals` implementation?

I know I can use the `=` operator in this case, but `EqualsNothing` is supposed to work with both classes and structures. The `=` operator will not work with classes in VB.NET, and it will also not work with structures that not have implemented this operator. `Equals` **does** work with everything, but as I demonstrated above, `Equals` doesn't return the same thing after boxing.

So, how should I rewrite `EqualsNothing` so that it works with classes and structures?

**Edit**: I tried making `EqualsNothing` generic, but that did not help.

Comment: It doesn't work because `Object.Equals` and `Integer.Equals` are different methods

Comment: @zerkms - I figured such thing would cause the problem, but do you know how to call the original `Equals`?

Comment: you cannot - you don't know what original method is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work in all cases, but you might try this generic method:

```
Sub Main
    Console.WriteLine(0.Equals(Nothing)) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(EqualsNothing(0)) 'True
End Sub

Private Function EqualsNothing(Of T)(ByVal item As T) As Boolean
  Dim i As T = Nothing
  Return (item.Equals(i))
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

I am normally a C# guy, so I used Linqpad to demonstrate this behavior with this code:

```
dim a as object
dim b as object
dim i as object
a = 0.Equals(Nothing)
Console.WriteLine("a={0}", a.ToString())
i = 0
b = i.Equals(Nothing)
Console.WriteLine("b={0}", b.ToString())
```

Putting 0 in the object i forces the box, just like calling the method.

The results, as the question indicates are:

```
a=True
b=False
```

The IL generated is:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.3     
IL_0003:  ldloca.s    03 
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0006:  call        System.Int32.Equals
IL_000B:  box         System.Boolean
IL_0010:  stloc.0     
IL_0011:  ldstr       "a={0}"
IL_0016:  ldloc.0     
IL_0017:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_001C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0021:  nop         
IL_0022:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0023:  box         System.Int32
IL_0028:  stloc.2     
IL_0029:  ldloc.2     
IL_002A:  ldnull      
IL_002B:  callvirt    System.Object.Equals
IL_0030:  box         System.Boolean
IL_0035:  stloc.1     
IL_0036:  ldstr       "b={0}"
IL_003B:  ldloc.1     
IL_003C:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_0041:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0046:  nop
```

As you can see, the difference is in what implementation of Equals is called.  In the first case, the Int32.Equals (Int32 is a CLR structure) is called.  This is a value equivilence check.

In the second instance, the Object.Equals is called which does a reference comparison--do the references point at the same object?

You should not expect the same behavior from these methods.

I would suggest that you need to ask yourself why are you comparing integers to Nothing?   They can NEVER be Nothing, but objects can, so the system's behavior is entirely appropriate.

Again, an Integer CANNOT be Nothing.  It is almost meaningless to compare it to Nothing--except that the CLR type system has a a contract that Equals has to return something.

So what you should do is reanalyze what you are doing so you are never comparing plain integers to Nothing, and never forcing the false box by the formal parameters of your procedure or function.  Instead, pass them as Integer by value so boxing does not happen.

---

If you absolutely positively have to do this, have two overloads.

```
Private Function EqualsNothing(ByVal item As Integer) As Boolean
Private Function EqualsNothing(ByVal item As Object) As Boolean
```

CLR semantics will select the non-boxed integer one preferntially.

I am writing this at 3:00 AM so not checking the VB syntax details above, since this is in response to comment discussion.

Or just force the thing to be unboxed:

```
Private Function EqualsNothing(ByVal item As Object) As Boolean

   Dim int As Integer = item

   Return int.Equals(Nothing)
End Function
```

Again, its late--syntax not checked.  The risk with this is that if the object is NOT an integer, you will get an exception.

Comment: Too kind, thank you.  I was really curious about this behavior :-)

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ - I know that structures like Integer can't be Nothing, but in VB.NET, comparing them to Nothing is a great way to test if the structure's value is the default value.

Comment: Note also the first `Nothing` is converted to `0` at compile time (see `IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0`, where as the second stays as "null" (`IL_002A:  ldnull`).

Comment: @RuudLenders Well, that explains the semantics of the `Int32.Equals` implementation.   It still strikes me as quite an odd coding practice. Unless it is a very well known convention in the VB community, it seems like it could lead to brittle code and hard to spot bugs.   I think the C# convention (`default(int)`) is much more clear, as it is not so easy to conflate with `null` and the meaning is crystal clear, even if you have never seen it before.

Comment: @MarkHurd I usually think of VB as just an alternate syntax to C# for CLR coding.  The shared libraries and the fact that so many features map one to one lead one into a false sense of confidence--it obviously has its own semantic subtleties and differences!   The code you point out emphasizes that Nothing in VB is also sometimes a stand in for the default value of the type, which WAS not documented on the Microsoft page on Nothing I checked.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: Hmmm... I +1ed your comment before checking... The [MSDN page for `Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx) starts "Represents the default value of any data type."!

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ - You've showed why `Equals` returns different values when a structure is boxed. Now, do you know how to avoid this difference? Ultimately I want `EqualsNothing(item)` to return the same as `item.Equals(Nothing)`.

Comment: Sorry @RuudLenders but I believe what I mentioned earlier is still correct--the question simply isn't meaningful.  If it is an int, comparing to nothing doesn't make sense, and you should not be doing it.  There is no way for you to change the semantics of the `Int32.Equals` implemtation.  THe closest you could come--and this is a bad idea--is to have an overload of your function taking an int (rather than an object) which will call the `Int32.Equals` implementation rather than the virtual object implementation.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ - Comparing an int to Nothing **does** make sense, as it is the equivalent for C#'s `default(int)`.

Comment: @RuudLenders  IF you take that interpretation--which I don't accept for reasons I already outlined above--then you should EXPECT different behaviors.

Comment: @RuudLenders Okay, see bottom of answer.  Use overloads.  I cave.  But I don't think it is a good idea :-)

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ - +1 for the overloads. However, can I avoid having to create an overload for every possible structure?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19980/discussion-between-saj14saj-and-ruud-lenders)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Equals, you can use IsNothing(object)

```
Private Function EqualsNothing(ByVal item As Object) As Boolean
 Return IsNothing(item)     
End Function
```

Comment: +1 for [IsNothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.80).aspx), having spend over 5 years in VB.NET development, I never heard about this function.

Comment: `IsNothing(0)` returns `False`, while `0.Equals(Nothing)` returns `True`. So your implementation of `EqualsNothing` still doesn't return what `Equals` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic of typed objects to you're advantage.

```
public function Compare(objLeft as Object,objRight as Object) as integer
    If TypeOf (objLeft) Is Integer Then
        return Cint(objLeft) = Cint(objRight)            
    ElseIf TypeOf (objLeft) Is DateTime Then
        'Your implementation here
    ElseIf TypeOf (objLeft) Is String Then
        'Your implementation here
    End If
end function
```

This is simply a question of de-boxing the objects but can be extended to support any type you use. Just be smart and place this functonality in a shared object compare so its not copy pasted everywhere.

Comment: Where do you declare `objField1`?